# What is the difference between a ConstraintException and an InvalidConstraintException?

Tags: .net, dataset

When working with .NET DataSets, what is the difference between a ConstraintException and an InvalidConstraintException?

I'm wondering why there isn't just one exception type - InvalidConstraintException. Why the need for two?